# Git rebase complication

Tags: git

Our off-shore developers accidentally merged a release branch into master before we were ready to release.  This left us with no master branch, and no ability to release hotfixes. I tried to fix this with a rebase, but don't quite understand what happened, I'm hoping someone can explain it. (And if there was a better way to do this)

Release branch was created from master (at point A), 
several feature branches merged into it (creating point B).  - so far so good.
Release branch merged into master (bad!) fast-forwarding master to point B.
work done on master (hotfixes, correct) bringing master to point C (from B).
work done on Release (bugfixes, correct) bringing Release to point D (from B).

what I wanted to achieve was to bring the changes from B to C onto point A, so that the changes from A to B are not included in point C any more (but point D remains unchanged).

I created a new branch from point A (new_Master), and did this:
git rebase --onto new_Master Release master

That did what I wanted, ie created a few new changesets after point A on new_Master (bringing it to point E), but it left the new_Master branch at point A, and I could not figure out how to move the label up to the new HEAD.  It also left the master branch at the old point C, but I was expecting it to roll back to point B at least, as those changes aren't supposed to be there at all any more.  So I've ended up with two checkins that represent the same changes, one set a child of A, and one a child of B.

Questions: 
1) How do I move the new_Master label to point E.  
2) How do I commit and push these changes to get them to the rest of the team?
3) Why does master still sit at point C?  (And why does point C still exist at all?)
4) How can I get the master label to move to point E (if possible) - which is on a different branch now?
5) This is clearly not how this was supposed to be done - so what was the right way to fix the mistake made by merging Release into master?

> 

Original graph
C D (Master C, Release D)
3 |
| 2
B/
1 
A

Final graph
E 
3
| C D (Master C, Release D)
| 3 |
| | 2
| B/
| 1
|/
A (new_Master)

Where I was trying to be:

E (Master, ideally, I'd be happy with new_Master pointing here))
3
| D (Release)
| 2
| B
| 1
A/

Comment: Wow, a diagram might be helpful here.

Comment: Rebase?  That doesn't sound desirable (at least, from my vantage point).  You may want a revert commit instead.

Comment: @Makoto - the accidental merge was a fast forward, so there was no commit TO revert.  The label for the master branch was just moved, and I don't know of a way to move it back (especially as there were more changes done post-merge, that needed to be applied to the right place in the history).

Comment: Maybe `git reflog` can help?

Comment: Well, even fast-forward merges leave their footprints in `git reflog`. So you at least can determine the correct point where to start. Then you should create a new branch named 'master-correct' in that point, cherry-pick all necessary commits if any from the current master and convince all your colleagues to switch to the 'master-correct'. After the transition is complete, and you're quite confident that noone is using old master, you may rename 'master' to 'master-broken' and 'master-correct' to 'master'. That's the transition plan.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know that `3` and `E` exist if you don't have any references (branches) pointing to them?

Comment: @BobSlocum - my local repo's HEAD is pointing at E, and I can see them in my repo graph...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `git checkout new_Master` followed by `git reset --hard <sha1 of E>`.

2) Depends what you want to share with your team. If you just want to share the new brach `new_Master` then you can obviously do something like `git push origin new_Master`, although I'm guessing you're more interested in getting `master` back to how it should be on the main repo? If so, you can do the following (with all the usual warnings about rebasing publicly visible branches)

Forcibly overwrite the broken `master` in your main repo with your new, correct `new_Master` (again, be doubly sure you know what's happening here)

```
git push origin new_Master:master -f
```

Then, get each person using the repo to do the following at home:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <sha1 of A>
git pull origin master
```

This will leave them with a master branch that looks like your new new_Master branch.

3) `git rebase --onto new_Master release master` should've changed `master` to point to `E`. I'm not sure what happened here.

4) `git reset --hard <sha1 of E>` while on master. Note that you wont be able to push master in your local repo into your shared repo as the histories will have diverged (see 2)

5) Yep. Here we go:

Get onto master so we can make a branch from it

```
git checkout master
```

Create a branch from `C` so we don't lose the reference to it in the next step

```
git branch master_backup
```

Move `master` back to A. We won't lose `C` because of the last step.

```
git reset --hard <sha1 for A>
```

Then add the changes from `B` to `C` onto `master`. Here the `release master_backup` specifies "Find the common ancestor of `release` and `master_backup` (`B`) and take all commits from there up until wherever `master_backup` is pointing (`C`)"

```
git rebase --onto master release master_backup
git checkout master
get merge master_backup
```

`master` now contains everything up to `A`, as well as the commits introduced between `B` and `C`. `release`, as far as I can tell, should still be exactly where you want it to be and require no changes.

Comment: This seems identical to what I did, apart from the fact that I chose to make a new branch for the "correct" endpoint, rather than a new branch to keep pointing at the old incorrect endpoint.  Is there a more fundamental difference that I'm missing?

Comment: Ha. Nah, you're right. It ends up being the same thing. I got lost between the typo and not having that wonderful diagram. I'll answer 2,3 and 4 then

Comment: getting master to where it should be is a short-term problem.  Once we release this current codebase, we would merge it into master anyway, so it's only a problem while QA is happening, and we have hotfixes to push out.  We can live with new_Master until then.  I don't want people to have to mess with their local repos before being able to work...

Comment: And 3 seems to be a "git not doing what it should" thing, and that's caused most of my confusion, so going to mark this one as correct, even though Paul Hick's answer is also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, in all honesty, that you want to to do a [revert](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) of that check-in instead.  Rebasing would rewrite the history of the commits, making it so that it "never happened" - but leaving you with a bit of a headache in cleaning up the commits.

What `git revert` allows you to do is to undo changes introduced by a merge (or likely any other commit).  If you later decide that you want those changes, you have to revert the revert (essentially, do a revert on the revert SHA).

Comment: There was no checkin to revert - the accidental merge was a fast-forward merge, so every checkin represents code changes that are needed in the final graph.

Answer (score 1):

**1) How do I move the new_Master label to point E.**

```
git checkout new_Master
git reset --hard <sha1 of E>
```

This will move new_Master to the same place as E.  Your previous command `git rebase --onto new_Master Release master` moved the commits that were on the master branch, but not on Release (that is, commit 3 as I read it) on top of new_Master.

**2) How do I commit and push these changes to get them to the rest of the team?**

```
git push <remote>
```

**3) Why does master still sit at point C? (And why does point C still exist at all?)**

master is just a pointer, just like new_Master.  You can move the pointer anywhere you like, even back in time.  It isn't done automatically when you rebase; that just moves the point that you're rebasing from.  To change where a branch points, checkout the branch then use `git reset`.

**4) How can I get the master label to move to point E (if possible) - which is on a different branch now?**

Assuming you want new_Master moved too, the simplest option is

```
git checkout new_Master
git branch -d master
git reset --hard <sha1 of E>
git branch master
```

This will delete master, move new_Master where you want it, then create a new master branch from new_Master.

**5) This is clearly not how this was supposed to be done - so what was the right way to fix the mistake made by merging Release into master?**

Lots of ways.  I probably wouldn't have reverted as suggested by others; not because it's wrong (it's not wrong), simply because I don't have any strong attachment to the name "master".  I think your approach was good enough for me, I'd just do it in what I think of as a more "seft documenting" manner.

1. Checkout master.
2. Create a new branch, perhaps `bad-merge`.
3. Reset master to A.
4. `git rebase --onto master Release bad-merge`
5. Note sha-1.
6. git checkout master
7. Reset master to new sha-1.

This would leave the tree the way I'd want it if that situation happened to me.

Comment: "Your previous command git rebase --onto new_Master master Release"

Ummm, sorry, I mean --onto new_Master Release master. I'll fix the question

I realise this invalidates most of your answer, I am sorry I got that the wrong way around...

Comment: I think 1) will get `now_Master` to `D` and 4) will get `master` to `A` (going by the diagram)

Comment: Fixed... I hope.  Learning by making mistakes.. this is the fastest (and most embarassing) way to learn ;)